# What is the best Linux distro to work with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

I use a Mac to develop in RoR, but a crisme of mine needs a Linux machine to develop.

I've tried to install Rails on Ubuntu and Debian 4 times each, but i got all kind of errors you can imagine.

Do someone have any distro that simply work with Rails? Or any tutorial to make this work on Ubuntu or Debian?

Comment: As far as I can tell, developing with RoR on Linux doesn't change much no matter what distro you choose. If you are lucky and don't encounter errors, everything from Gentoo to Debian is the same.

Comment: shouldn't you ask in http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ? Any way any Linux distro is good the problem may be deployment of it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails

Comment: any linux distro works as charm....i'm on ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just about any linux distro will work fine. Use [RVM](https://rvm.io), install via instructions and follow the guide for your platform. Once RVM is up and running use gem (and gemsets) to install Rails.

Skip the distro's package manager for Ruby. It will likely be out of date.

Comment: Using RVM seems to work! I'm trying it right now!

Comment: http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-install-ruby-1-9-2-and-rails-3-0-on-ubuntu-10-10-4148.html -> Very nice tutorial on how to install Rails on Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter.  Use that you know better.  If you don't use any linux distro get that use nearest guru.